# How i implement my JSON API Request into a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, json-api, swift5, wordpress-json-api

I have a problem with my current Project. First of all, i like to implement a `JSON` API Request that allows me to get a title off a URL. The Problem: I want to display the `JSON` data into a `UITableViewCell`.

But `Xcode` throws following Error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'FirstViewController.Title' to type
>   'String?'

Maybe there is more wrong in my code, because i'm just a beginner at Swift/Xcode

I already tried this:

`cell.textLabel?.text = course.title as? String`

But i got warning message as follows:

`Cast from 'FirstViewController.Title' to unrelated type 'String' always fails`

This is my code sample:

```
var courses = [Course]()
let cell = "ItemCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchJSON()
}

struct Course: Codable {
    let title: Title

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case links = "_links"
    }
}

struct Links: Codable {
}

struct Title: Codable {
    let rendered: String
}


fileprivate func fetchJSON() {
    let urlString = "ExampleURL"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to get data from url:", err)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {

                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self, from: data)


                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Failed to decode:", jsonErr)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return courses.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "ItemCell")
    let course = courses[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = course.title as? String // Cast from 'FirstViewController.Title' to unrelated type 'String' always fails
    return cell
}
```

I just want to get `WordPress` posts into a `UITableView` - `UITableViewCell`.

Maybe you can tell me if its the wrong way i tried it but i don't really know how i solve this problem

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the json returned is a dictionary not an array meaning if a dictionary your decode with `Course.self` is correct if an array then you should use `[Course].self` BTW check this to see whether the decoder will fail or not `print("Failed to decode:", jsonErr)`

Comment: It is a dictionary json, because xcode gives me a bunch of titles that i need from the json data. I thought that my request is correct and my implemantation into the cell is wrong. I also tryed to use `[Course].self` but when i run it, i became no output in my console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assign the var before the reload

```
 let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Course.self, from: data)
 courses.append(res)
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

And set it to the string value

```
 cell.textLabel?.text = course.title.rendered
```

---

```
 courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
 print(courses)
```

Comment: When i implement it and run the project, xcode gives me this error: 
`Failed to decode: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: your root is an array then try edit............. and post errors if Any , also print the array as it may be empty

Comment: Yes, omg thank you. Xcode displayed me all titles that i needed. You are saving my life thank you. But there is one more question: When i need more information from the JSON data how i implement it? One more Struct i thought, isnt it?